# Django:General help in testing

Tags: python, django

I know this is more of a learning thing than a problem in programming but still I need to ask it.Please don't down vote it,I wouldn't have asked it here if I knew any other appropriate place.I have a view as follows:

```
def takedown(request,aid):
    approveobj = get_object_or_404(approve,pk=aid)

    # fetching mapping
    map = mapping.objects.get(appval=approveobj)

    try:
        # deleting option from main database
        map.optval.delete()

        # changing the status of the appval
        map.appval.status = 'Pending'
        map.appval.save()

        # finally deleting the map
        map.delete()

    except:
        print("Error in taking down the entry")

    redirect_url = "/wars/configure/"+str(map.appval.warval.id)+"/"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

I want to design some tests for the above view.At present I'm checking whether it redirects to appropriate url or not.What else I can test?I need to test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your view, I can see three other possible tests:

- Test that the view returns status code 404 for an `aid` that does not exist
- Check that the map object exists in the database. Fetch the view in your test, then check that the map object has been deleted as you expected.
- Test that your view works as expected when there is an exception in the try except block. It's not clear what you're expecting to go wrong here. Note that because you only print the error, nothing will be displayed to the user so it's tricky to test this.

Comment: Thanks you very much.I should start writing some tests now:)

Comment: One more thing.How can I load the view in my test?

Comment: Use `self.client.get` (or `self.client.POST` if you're posting data to the url). There are [examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#example).

Comment: Okay,I though by 'load' you meant something other than 'post' or 'get'.:)

Comment: I wrote this test,but It is useless as it's not throwing assertion error because '2000' doesn't exist.On the real web browser my view is wroking flawlessly.What can be the problem?
def test_takedown(self):
  # checking the view
  res = self.c.get('/approval/approve/2000')
  self.assertEqual(res.status_code,301)
  map = mapping.objects.all()
  print(len(map))
  res = self.c.get('/approval/takedown/2')
  self.assertEqual(res.status_code,301)

Comment: Pasting functions in the comments isn't a good idea, the lack of formatting makes them difficult to read. The tests do not use the real database. You have to create [`fixtures`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.fixtures), or create the objects in the test itself. See the docs for more info.